# How can I get the model index from Qcombobox

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

I fill a Qcombobox with using setModel method:

```
    def fill_cbo(self, list, cboBox):
        d = tuple(list)
        print(d)
      
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        for id_, value in d:
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(value)
            it.setData(id_, IdRole)
            model.appendRow(it)

        if cboBox == 'casesCbo':
            self.casesCbo.setModel(model)
```

later in the program I want to access the model index when a user selects an item in the combobox. The problem is I can't access the model directly anymore and casesCbo.CurrentIndex() just gives me the index based on an integer. How do I access the model index or more specifically the first item from the tuple?

I tried casesCbo.item(Data()) and it isnt working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QComboBox is fundamentally a *mono dimensional view* widget, so, the [`currentIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop) function returns the selected *index* of the shown *list*, which is the "row" number in the visible popup, similarly to an index of a basic Python list or tuple.

If you want the QModelIndex, you need to access the combo *model*:

```py
    def getModelIndex(self, index, combo):
        model = combo.model()
        item = model.item(index)
        modelIndex = model.indexFromItem()
```

Note that the above is only valid if the following requirements are met:

- you are using a QStandardItemModel;
- the reference column is always the first column (see the [`modelColumn`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#modelColumn-prop) property of QComboBox;
- the model is bidimensional and the combo does not use a *different root index* of a child element (consider tree models like QFileSystemModel);

A more appropriate syntax of the above, then, should be the following, which would work for any properly implemented model, and for any situation, including using different column and root index of the model within the combo:

```py
    def getModelIndex(self, index, combo):
        modelIndex = combo.model().index(
            index, combo.modelColumn(), combo.rootIndex())
```

The above syntax just follows the basic [`index()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index) implementation of any Qt model.

Note that if you only need access to model data and the model properly implements the [`ItemDataRole` enum](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum), you can just use the [`itemData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#itemData) function:

```py
    def getComboData(self, index):
        data = combo.itemData(index, SomeRole)
```

Just remember that the `itemData()` implementation uses `Qt.UserRole` as default role, so you need to explicitly use the correct role, and you will always get what the `data()` function of that model returns.

For instance, if you added an item that *actually* and *only* has a value set as a `DisplayRole` used with an integer (with `item.setData(intValue, Qt.DisplayRole)` or `comboItem.setItemData(index, intValue, Qt.DisplayRole)`), then the value of `itemData(index)` will not be the same as `itemData(index, Qt.DisplayRole)`, nor that of `itemText(index)` (which always returns a string representation of that combo index).

Please carefully check the QComboBox documentation in order to better understand all its underlying aspects.